# How to run python neural network keras script in c# .net core app

Tags: c#, python, .net, keras, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to run python neural network script in witch using imports:

```
from keras.models import Sequential    
from keras.layers import Dense    
from keras.callbacks import History    
from keras.models import load_model    
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
np.random.seed(7)    
import pandas as pd    
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split    
from keras import optimizers
```

I try to run it using IronPython but this dont worked. IronPython dont recognise keras.models etc...
I also try to run it with System.Diagnostic.Process but this solution also dont worked. It run only simple python scripts with some prints.

I need just to execute .py script from .cs class.

I try examples with cmd.exe with run .py script with but they dont worked.

Is there any way to run python neural network script in c# app? It must be very simple.

EDIT:
One of my solutions:
    string fileName =

```
string fileName="C:/Users/FUJITSU/source/repos/CardiologicClinic_WebApp/CardiologicClinic_WebApp/AI/xd.py";
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\FUJITSU\PycharmProjects\NIDUC\venv\Scripts\python.exe", fileName);
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:/Users/FUJITSU/source/repos/CardiologicClinic_WebApp/CardiologicClinic_WebApp/AI";
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                p.Close();
```

And error produced:

```
line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import load_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
 string fileName = "path to script.py";
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"path to python.exe", fileName);
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "path to working dir";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
```

This worked fine for me.

Optionaly you can hide process with this command:

```
p.startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that every python library will work in IronPython. Posting any error messages you do have would be helpful in finding a solution.

Instead, try calling python using the C# version of `system('python myscript.py')`. It is sure to be tough going though getting two languages to work together.

(If I could comment, I would have made this a comment instead. Your forgiveness, please.)

Comment: This may help:
https://medium.com/better-programming/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5

Comment: thanks but this dont work for me -> error "no module named keras.model"

Comment: Yes. IronPython can not do what you want. You will have Python do what you want. Please see the medium article I linked in my previous comment. It shows you how to call a python process from c#. Good luck.